# Elasticsearch Search Engine not returning results for certain fields

Tags: php, html, elasticsearch

I've a simple search engine which works fine for searching in my database. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be returning search result for everything. What I mean by this is that if I search for something under the "name" field I get a result, but if I search for something in the "title" or "director" field for example I do not get a result. Even if one of my "title" is something like "The Godfather", searching for that title wiill not return me any results. Meanwhile, searching for "1972", which is the "year" it was made and one of my fields, do give me an result. This result shows me "title", the "director", and the "year". Searching for any of those other two using those results returns nothing.

I'm a novice at php and elasticsearch so there might be something obvious which I'm doing wrong. If you need any other details to help me I'll be happy to provide them. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2.

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();
$es = $client;
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $query = $es->search([
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => $q,
                            'type' => 'phrase_prefix',
                            'fields' => [
                                'name', 'type', 'content',
                                'title', 'director', 'year',
                                'play_name', 'speaker'],
                            'operator' => 'and'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
}   
if($query['hits']['total'] >=1 ) {
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
}
?>
<!doctype html> 
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Søkemotor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="img/DigRevLogo" alt="Logo" width="600" height="150" class="img">
        </div>

        <div class="search">
            <form action="index.php" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="search_form">
                <label>

                    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Søk her">
                </label>

                <label><input type="submit" value="Søk" name="s"></label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        $noresult = "Ingen resultat på søket av $q.";
        if(isset($results)) {
            foreach($results as $r) {
        ?>
            <div class="result">
                <a href="#<?php echo $r['_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r['_source']['name'];?></a> 
                <a href="#<?php echo $r['_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r['_source']['title'];?></a>
                <a href="#<?php echo $r['_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r['_source']['play_name'];?></a>
                <br>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['type'];?> 
                <?php echo $r['_source']['director'];?> 
                <br>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['content'];?>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['year'];?>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['speaker']?>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['description'];?>
            </div>
            <div class="noresult">
        <?php 
            }
        }
            else echo "<CENTER>$noresult</CENTER>";
        ?>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually you can diagnose why it doesn't work by running the same query on the `<host>/<index>/<type>/<document>/_explain` endpoint e.g. if you want to check why you can't find movie with id 1 on the movies index you can do `127.0.0.1:9200/movies/movie/1/_explain` and send the query as postdata (POSTMAN can help with this)

Comment: A bit more information would be good. What kind of mapping did you use? Do you really need a phrase_prefix query?

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Ah, no. Should've mentioned that I added the phrase_prefix type to try and solve another problem I had. It is not completely neccecary but even if I remove it the problem presists. As for mapping I'm not sure what you want to know but for example the document with the "title" of "The Godfather" is located as lochalhost:9200/movies/movie/1 and under _source have the fields "title", "director2, and "year.